# Controlling calculation procedure in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a specific question concerning the calculation procedure in Excel. Thing is, I have a couple of rather "slow" functions that I have implemented myself in VBA. Everytime I open the specific workbook, or only make a small change in a worksheet, everything have to calculate and thus, take a very long time (annoying).

I wonder if there is a way, other than just checking "manual calculation" under "options/formulas", to control certain (self-implemented) VBA-functions to calculate ONLY on demand (with press of a button for instance)? The most optimal solution would be to be able to have all other formulas to be calculated automatically, and the remaining VBA formulas only calculated when needed.

Thanks,
N

Comment: Perhaps "Treat the cause, not the symptoms" - why are your calcs so slow?

Comment: Yeah, I know :) I'm just asking if there is a way to work around that first bit...

Comment: Bullseye@MitchWheat :)

Comment: Some code would be helpful.  You might want to try Application.ScreenUpdating = False (in case you've forgotten something obvious) before running the calculations.  And then setting it true after calculations are done.

Comment: Hi guys. I tried the solution below and yes, it works. But as a matter of fact, I also tried @MitchWheat tip, i.e. to actually fix the "cause" - works like a clock. Just me being lazy to start with I guess. Thanks for the motivation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a control cell that links to your VBA functions.

If cell A1 = 1 fire script, else end.

Then when you want it to calculate make it a 1, else a 0?

You could do it with a tick box to make in slightly more elegant. :)